# scalac v javac and scala v java

Tags: java, scala, jar, jvm

So, I understand how the scalac compiler is different from javac - looking at the bytecodes produced, they looked nothing like what javac would produce - e.g. a class without a constructor.

But is the runtime any different than starting java with scala jars in the classpath? I am very certain but can someone confirm that the scala command is just a thin wrapper around java - after all they simply lauch a JRE / JDK.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `scala` command is basically a script that sets up the classpath and then runs your code in the Java Runtime environment.

The relevant line in the `scala` script appears at the end:

```
exec "${JAVACMD:=java}" $JAVA_OPTS -cp "$TOOL_CLASSPATH" -Dscala.home="$SCALA_HOME" -Denv.emacs="$EMACS"  scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner  "$@"
```

Basically, this starts `java` running `MainGenericRunner`.  `MainGenericRunner` then checks whether you have told `scala` to run one of your Scala classes.  If so, it starts running that.  Otherwise, it stars up the interactive interpreter.

Comment: I think as long as I have a mixed mode project, I will stick to using "java" with scala jars in the classpath. Thanks.

Comment: Is there a github link to the code line that you have added?

Answer (score 3):

Scala (on linux, anyway) is a script.  The contents can be seen by typing `more```which scala``

You are mostly right, it basically sets up an environment and then runs java.

Comment: This is indeed confusing a bit, `java` should properly be called `jvm` as it will run any code compiled to java byte code, no matter from what language. The converse is also true: If the `java` command will not run the code, then so no other program (except it contains a custom implementation of the JVM).

Answer (score 1):

Yes; you can trivially confirm this by running your scala application direct from `java`, but with the `scala-library.jar` on the classpath. It works - there really is **no magic** going on in the `scala` executable. This is how I run all my scala applications.